# Would an Ethernet spliter work for two devices that won't get used at the same time?

Tags: ethernet

I have a single Ethernet cable rubbing into my room and I was wondering if I would be able to hook up my PC and my Xbox using a spliter, only one device will be used at a time.( And if anyone was wondering my internet speed is crap, like 0.5 - 2  mb/s on a good day)

Comment: What kind of splitter? Can you link to an example you have in mind?

Comment: There is no such thing as an ethernet splitter. I think you mean an ethernet switch or hub. The UTP ethernet standards call for one four-pair cable per connection. If you only have one cable, you can only connect one device, but that device could be a cheap switch.

Comment: I've encountered what folks have called "splitters" which take an 4-pair Cat5 cable and turn it into two 2-pair cables, enabling two 100Base-TX connections. [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140707221928/http://www.trinetusa.com/images/catalog/pages31-40.pdf)

Comment: I see what you mean, a spliter is used so you don't have to run two cables but you still need two ports on the incoming side for each device

Comment: Thanks for all the info I now know what I need and what a spliter is actually for

Comment: @source, those cable splitters are not for ethernet since they violate network standards, but they do exist.

Comment: Welcome to superuser, we arn't a forum, we're a Q&A site. Rather than posting a comment as an answer, you may choose to upvote useful answers and pick the most correct answer with a checkmark

Answer (score 3):

I highly discourage using any sort of splitter for a network cable.

Instead, spend $10 on a cheap Fast Ethernet switch such as [this one](http://a.co/4KmylPs):

[image]

Plug your network cable from the wall into this switch, then connect your PC and your XBox to the switch as well.  Both devices will work happily and you won't have to worry about messing with your cabling.

As @David Schwartz mentioned, if you can spring an [extra $7](http://a.co/4UPcZCu) you can upgrade to a full Gigabit Ethernet switch, which runs about 10 times faster than the Fast Ethernet switch. You may not need it today, but you very well could find a reason to need it in the future [like if you get better Internet ;-)].

Comment: If you can spring for a $15-$20 solution, you can get a gigabit switch. While it won't matter much for just Internet access, it might if you ever add a local media server or NAS device.

Answer (score 1):

No. The device you are referring to can only be used to run two links over a single cable by using one splitter at each end. Since you only want one link, and would have no way to wire a splitter at the other end, it won't work.

Comment: Well, actually it would work if he used such a splitter on **both** ends of the cable run.  Though, if the ethernet cable is plugged directly into a cable or DSL modem, he'll need to buy a switch anyway.  In that case, better to just locate the switch in the bedroom and not bother with splitters.

Comment: If he used two such splitters and connected both ports on the other splitter to ports on a router or switch, then it will work, yes. But getting a cheap switch would probably be a much better choice.

Comment: Yes I definitely agree with you.  I was simply disagreeing with the blanket statement that it wouldn't work.  It **can** work, but cost and effort required make it a poor solution.